# Supported devices is 0-Google play

Tags: android, google-play

Manifest:
This was working fine before some time. Now it shows 0-supported devices!
Please help me on this.

Shows these features on console though I am not using it.
    android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
    android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
    android.hardware.WIFI

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.irb.wallpro"
    android:versionCode="5"
    android:versionName="1.0.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- Include next permission if you want to allow UIL to cache images on SD card -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />

       <application
        android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.ui.WallProApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.ui.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.ui.PropertiesActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.ui.HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.ui.EULA"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.ui.AboutActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:taskAffinity="com.app.irbrothers.wallpro.AppWall"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:taskAffinity="com.app.irbrothers.wallpro.AppWall"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <service android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.alarm.NotificationService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.irbrothers.wallpro.recievers.NotificationAlarmReciever" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.irbrothers.notification" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Solved**
Do not use any library which is already present in framework. Ex: "json-simple" here.

Comment: Do you upload the release apk? Make sure that you don't upload the debug one.

Comment: Are you compiling with Gradle? If so please add your Gradle settings of your application.

Comment: No. I am using eclipse to compile. and its not debug enabled one.